# Printing out character properties returns a blank table?

Tags: lua, roblox

In Roblox, I'm trying to print out the full table of properties from the character but when I do print it out, the table is empty.

I tried waiting for when the character was created and then getting its children, and I was expecting it to print out literally everything but nothing was being printed.

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local Player = Players.LocalPlayer
local Character = Player.Character or Player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
print(Character:GetChildren())
```

Answer (score 1):

Right before you `print`, add a `wait()`.

Allowing your localscript to temporarily yield after the `CharacterAdded:Wait()` signal will give just enough time for the engine to add the children.